# unload Snowflake data to s3 without the extension/file_format

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, file-format

How can I unload snowflake data to s3 without using any file format?

For unloading the data into a specific extension we use file format in snowflake.

E.g. code

```
  copy into 's3://mybucket/unload/'
  from mytable
  storage_integration = myint
  file_format = (format_name = my_csv_format);
```

But what I want is to store data without any extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SINGLE` is what I was looking for. It is one of parameters we can use with `COPY` command which creates the file without extension.

Code:

```
copy into 's3://mybucket/unload/'
from mytable
storage_integration = myint
file_format = (format_name = my_csv_format)
SINGLE = TRUE;
```

Go through note of below link for better understanding:

[https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html#:~:text=comma%20(%2C)-,FILE_EXTENSION,-%3D%20%27string%27%20%7C%20NONE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html#:%7E:text=comma%20(%2C)-,FILE_EXTENSION,-%3D%20%27string%27%20%7C%20NONE)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the parameter FILE_EXTENSION = NONE to your file format. With this parameter Snowflake is not adding a file extension based on your file format (in this case .csv), but is using the passed extension (NONE or any other).

```
copy into 's3://mybucket/unload/'
from mytable
storage_integration = myint
file_format = (format_name = my_csv_format file_extension = NONE);
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html